# Angular sort by Number, String and Date types

Tags: angular, sorting

I have a table and would like to sort it in Angular

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Create Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <tr *ngFor="let item of items | orderBy: order:reverse:'case-insensitive':comparator ">
             <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
             <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
             <td>{{ item.createDate }}</td> 
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and data

```
this.items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: meow,
    createDate: Tue Mar 20 14:15:23 MDT 2018
  },
  {
    id:2,
    name: meow2,
    createDate: Fri Mar 23 14:15:23 MDT 2018
  },
  {
    id:3,
    name: meow2,
    createDate: Sun Mar 20 14:15:23 MDT 2013
  }
]
```

and table.component.ts

```
comparator(value: any, args?: any): any { 
    let newVal = value.sort((a: any, b: any) => { 
        let date1 = new Date(a.date); 
        let date2 = new Date(b.date); 
        if (date1 > date2) { return 1; } 
        else if (date1 < date2) { return -1; } 
        else { return 0; } 
    }); 
    return newVal; 
}
```

So far, I am using ngx-sort-pipe https://github.com/VadimDez/ngx-order-pipe

It can sort number and string perfectly.

However, it will sort date by alphabetical order as well.

Based on my data format, how can I not only sort by number and string, but also sort by date.

Is there a way to do sort by different types, such as number, string and date format?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please share your attempted code.

Comment: Date can be sorted as is, in yyyy-MM-dd format . Just an idea.

Comment: @HassanImam Thank you. I have put the code

Comment: @SamwellTarly Thank you so much. It helps. I can just change the pass date format to yyyy-MM-dd and then it can sort perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing comparator to

```
comparator(value: any, args?: any): any { 
    if(this.order=='createDate'){
        let newVal = value.sort((a: any, b: any) => { 
            let date1 = new Date(a.date); 
            let date2 = new Date(b.date); 
            if (date1 > date2) { return 1; } 
            else if (date1 < date2) { return -1; } 
            else { return 0; } 
        }); 
        return newVal; 
    } else {
        return value.sort();
    }
}
```